# I am not able to get properties from an ontology file

Tags: java, eclipse, jena, owl, ontology

I am not able to get properties from an ontology file. I am new to ontology and apache jena. And also I am not able to use 'getProperty' command in proper way.
Till these code I am able to get classes but I don't know how to use 'getProperty','listObjectsOfProperty' command to get properties.

```
package onto1;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.semarglproject.vocab.OWL;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;


public class ontolo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        String inputFileName = "file:///F:/apache-jena-2.12.1/travel.owl";

        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( inputFileName );
        if (in == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
        }
        //Property hasTime = model.createProperty( "file:///F:/apache-jena-2.12.1/shopping.owl#" );
        //Property getProperty ( inputFileName, hastime) ;

        model.read(in, null);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property irrr = model.getProperty(OWL.ON_PROPERTIES);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator iter1 = model.listObjectsOfProperty(irrr);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResIterator i = model.listSubjectsWithProperty (irrr);
        //com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement iir = model.getRequiredProperty(inputFileName, irrr);
        //com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator iter2 = model.listObjectsOfProperty(inputFileName.subClassOf);
        ExtendedIterator<OntClass> iter = ((OntModel) model).listClasses();

           while ( iter.hasNext()){

               System.out.println(iter.next().toString());
           }


        // write it to standard out
        model.write(System.out);

        }



    }
```

Comment: getProperty doesn't appear anywhere in your code.  What's not working?  Please show a minimal working example of something that you *expect* (or would like) to work that isn't, along with what you expect it to produce and what it's actually producing.

Comment: I hadn't posted complete code because I was not able to understand how to use "getproperites' and other command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which "getProperty" are you trying to use?  [Resource.getProperty](http://goo.gl/lZ3UUS) or [Model.getProperty](http://goo.gl/Iy4FGZ)?

Comment: In above code I am trying to use 'Model.getProperty' but I don't know which 'getProperty' I should use. My main goal is to find properties from ontology file.

Comment: You just want a list of properties used in the model?  E.g., if the model was the set of triple {(a p b) (a q c) (b  r d)}, you want the list [p, q, r]?

Comment: Yeah, I want a list of properties from ontology(.owl) file

Comment: Well, there's not a simple method for doing that.  You can either iterate through the statements in the model and look at the property of each triple, or you could use a very simple SPARQL query (which would allow you to eliminate duplicates): `select distinct ?p where { ?s ?p ?o }`.